# Node.js : Export module

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new to node.js. Recently I learnt that when object is exported from a file, the same can be consumed in other file using require("FILE_NAME").

In many of my apps, am using require('mongoose'). From where this is getting exported? I could not find module.export for mongoose anywhere. My understanding can be wrong. Please help me in understanding the concept.

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you require something, Node will look into the `node_modules` directory (global and local), where all of your dependencies lie or the file path you have specified in case of a path.

Search for `mongoose` in `node_modules`, you should be able to find it.

Comment: Just couple of quick clarifications
1) 'mongoose' is a folder and not a file. So I understand require('FOLDER_NAME') does the same here right?
2) Inside mongoose/index.js, i found the line====> module.exports = require('./lib/');  And inside mongoose/lib/index.js different prototypes are defined such as model, connect etc... which we are using in our code. right?

Comment: Exactly! When a folder is referenced, it'll seek ```index.js``` inside the folder.

Comment: @VIJAYU Please mark this answer as correct, if you are pleased by the answer.

Comment: Hi Suhas, I up voted it, but it did not reflect as i dont hyave enough reputation thing. not too sure what to do.